# In MODx revolution, how can I restrict the editing of resources within a container to a user group?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am using MODx revolution and I have watched the video at: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Security

I have a resource that is a container. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to setup a user group that only has permissions to add/edit/delete/unpublish/publish documents within that container rather than generically across all resources and containers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to archieve this with [resource groups](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Resource+Groups). Just create a resource group, put all resources on root level *but* your container to it and apply security measures as usual with Groups, Roles and ACLs on that resource group. Child resources of resources in the resource group (also new ones) will be treated as part of the resource group, so they will never show up to users, that don't have rights to view that resource group.

This only works, if your container is on root level because all resources above your container have to be at least visible. It is possible, to do this with several resource groups, too, but in this case I'd advice you to put your container in a [context](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Contexts) on his own and grant some users access to that context only and not to the standard `mgr` context.

You can find out how to do this in detail in the [RTFM](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Security) or in this very comprehensive [guide](http://bobsguides.com/revolution-permissions.html) by Bob Ray.

Comment: What about if the container was on a second level? Would I just need to give those permissions to its parent (and have to be okay with the fact that those users could potentially change anything within it's parent)?

Comment: As usual, Bobs guide was very useful. Thanks!

Comment: If your container is on second level, you might put its parent in a resource group that the users are able to load and view, but not to save any changes. Should be easier than integrating a second context just for that.